# If innerHTML includes x, y, z, etc, then replaceWith -- need solution for multiple innerHTML variations

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a short script that looks for specific classes with specific text in innerHTML, and then uses replaceWith to replace the entire element. This works great when there's only one specific piece of text, but I have several items I want to locate and replace.

The HTML code below is simplified. Basically, there's another script that finds specific terms and, on first occurrence of those terms, adds a popup with a definition. There are some terms that I'd like to omit, but modifying the other script isn't a possibility. The first solution I threw together involves finding the popup class, looking at its innerHTML for a consistent beginning (it will always start with term followed immediately by a span tag) and then replacing the entire element with the term as normal text ("term").

```js
let glossaryTerms = document.getElementsByClassName('popup');
for (let x = 0; x < glossaryTerms.length; x++) {
    let term = glossaryTerms[x];
    let content = term.innerHTML.trim();
        if (content.includes('term\<span')) {
           term.replaceWith('term');
        }
}
```

```html
<p>Sample text for this example. Then there's a word with a definition popup <a  href="#" class="popup #text">term<span class="popupBody">This is the definition text that appears in the popup eventually...</span></a>.</p>
```

That script works just fine, but I may have a couple dozen terms.

For example:
apple
banana
cactus

And so on.

Any advice here is greatly appreciated. I was wondering if the terms could be stored in a JSON file, for example, but I'd have no idea where to start.

Comment: [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method with a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) are the tools for the task. But they're not to be used to fork the HTML, though.

Comment: Instead of giving an example that works, could you give an example where it does not work, and explain what is wrong?

Comment: @trincot I need to know how to expand this script to work with multiple terms. How would I create a similar script that looks for term<span and replaces it with term, and then apple<span and replaces that with apple, and then banana<span and replace it with banana.

Comment: Oh I see, your use of the word "term" is a bit confusing, because in your code you name a variable `term` that stands for a complete node.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I definitely see how that's confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to extract the first text (preceding the first child element) is:

```
node.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
```

... as this will regard the `span`-node as the *second* node, provided that there is text preceding it.

There is also a second issue: the collection returned by `getElementsByClassName` is a *live* collection, i.e. when you replace those popup nodes with plain text, you actually reduce the size of that collection. So what was the second element, suddenly becomes the first (at index 0), yet  your loop increases the index, so you *skip* a node.

A solution is to use a non-live alternative `querySelectorAll`:

```js
let terms = new Set(["apple", "pear"]); // Only do something for these terms
for (let node of document.querySelectorAll('.popup')) {
    let term = node.childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
    if (terms.has(term)) node.replaceWith(term);
}
```

```html
<p>Sample text for this example. Then there's a word with a definition popup 
<a  href="#" class="popup #text">apple<span class="popupBody">
This is the definition text that appears in the popup eventually...</span></a>.</p>

<p>Sample text for this example. Then there's a word with a definition popup 
<a  href="#" class="popup #text">pear<span class="popupBody">
This is the definition text that appears in the popup eventually...</span></a>.</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing out those problems! There's a caveat, of course, that I failed to mention. It's likely that I'll have <a class="popup"> elements that should not be altered.

For example, a page may have "apple", "banana" and "pear" and I don't want to replace "banana" -- just the other two. Is it possible to store "apple" and "pear" in a variable, and then check whether or not node is equal to that variable and then do the replace? (Hopefully I am making sense.)  Thanks again!

Comment: Great -- thanks again for your help. I just needed to add square brackets to the set, and now I am all set. Much better! I appreciate the tips, answers, and explanations!

Comment: Ah yes, the argument to `Set` needed that correction. Good to hear it is useful!